# Access potentially cached websites (Chrome)

Tags: internal-storage, chrome-for-android, cache

Having difficulty with my insurance company and would appreciate some help. I have in my browser history on Chrome on my Android Phone that I accessed the insurance site, and a particular page, to update my policy.

They claim I didn't do this and are refusing to insure me.

I've used the /:cache in the address bar but this only goes back a few hours. Is there a way to see anything further back?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you archived the page using [archive.is](http://archive.is) or [archive.org](http://archive.org), I don't think it is possible. Googles cache is updated every few days.

Comment: Explaining how archiving can be done on mobile browser would help

Comment: @beeshayams I believe just using "Request Desktop Site" should allow you to archive pages on a mobile device.